# Interpolate large data Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I'm working on a Python project that uses `NumPy` and `SciPy`. I have the following:

```
x = numpy.arange(-5,5,0.01)
y = numpy.arange(-5,5,0.01)
```

I also have a function of `x` and `y` such that

```
# fxy = function of x and y in a grid
# fxy.shape = (y.shape[0], x.shape[0])
```

I want to interpolate `fxy` such that I have the function values at `x` and `y` points that are `0.0001` or `0.001` apart, i.e. I want to evaluate the function `fxy` at

```
finer_x = numpy.arange(-5,5,0.0001)
finer_y = numpy.arange(-5,5,0.0001)

# finer_fxy = function of finer_x and finer_y in a grid
# finer_fxy.shape = (finer_y.shape[0], finer_x.shape[0])
```

I keep trying to use the `bisplrep` and `interp2d` functions in `scipy.interpolate` but I get

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/fitpack.py", line 873, in bisplrep
tx,ty,nxest,nyest,wrk,lwrk1,lwrk2)
MemoryError
```

and

```
OverflowError: Too many data points to interpolate
```

respectively using those functions. What's the best way to create the interpolated data?

Comment: is it class work? If yes, add homework tag

Comment: If `finer_fxy` is stored in the probably-default `float64`s, this would take about 64 GiB of memory; not surprising that you're running out. If you're willing to interpolate to .001 instead, that'd be a little less than a gig, which is much more reasonable.

Comment: Not classwork/homework. 0.001 is acceptable, actually, for my purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, you're putting too many points on your NumPy plate, sorry about to hear about that.

My advice would be to first plot your data, to find zones that are relatively linear, and skip them. That is, try to decompose your arrays into different zones, and perform a piece-wise interpolation.

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks! I read something similar in a previous SO post, was wondering if I'm missing something before trying it out.

Comment: The critical point will be to decompose your data smartly. For example, if you see some linear trend on a given interval `[a:b]`, you may want to consider one interval before the midpoint `(a+b)/2` and one after...

Answer (score 1):

Your data is on a regular grid: try using RectBivariateSpline.

bisplrep/interp2d are for scattered data.